# Why is there a obj_method = obj.method pattern in Python code sometimes?

Tags: python

I'd like to know what is the reason behind using it and when does this pattern help.

Several examples are in collections module. First in [`_count_elements`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fecb48a1d84190c37214eb4b0c8d5460300a78b/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L480):

```
def _count_elements(mapping, iterable):
    'Tally elements from the iterable.'
    mapping_get = mapping.get
    for elem in iterable:
        mapping[elem] = mapping_get(elem, 0) + 1
```

and in [`Counter.update`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fecb48a1d84190c37214eb4b0c8d5460300a78b/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L631):

```
if iterable is not None:
    if isinstance(iterable, _collections_abc.Mapping):
        if self:
            self_get = self.get
            for elem, count in iterable.items():
                self[elem] = count + self_get(elem, 0)
```

Comment: I'd say it is because of performance. `self.get` probably takes more time than `self_get` since it is a lookup. And collections might be pretty big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both these examples, there's a performance reason for doing that. Calling the '.' operator on an object needs to look up the attribute / method (e.g. `get` in the above example) in the object's set of attributes. By assigning the method to a new variable (e.g. `self_get`, you save the need to do this lookup in every iteration.